# Count distinct of multiple columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've been trying to figure a query out.

Let's say a table looks like this:

```
cus_id   prod_category   agreement_id    type_id
111         10                123456        1
111         10                123456        1
111         10                123456        2
111         20                123456        2
123         20                987654        6
999          0                135790        99
999          0                246810        99


and so on...
```

I would like to get the count of prod_category for **distinct** values over **agreement_id** and **type_id**

so I would like to get a result like this:

```
cus_id     prod_id     count
111          10          2
111          20          1
123          20          1
999           0          2
```

Comment: **What DBMS are you using?** You seem to want per (cus_id, prod_category) tuple the count of distinct (agreement_id, type_id) tuples. This means `GROUP BY cus_id, prod_category` and `COUNT DISTINCT agreement_id, type_id)`. The latter (`COUNT DISTINCT` on tuples), however, is not supported by all DBMS. So while this will work for some DBMS, you'll need a workaround for others.

Comment: I am using snowflake

Comment: With snowflake `COUNT(DISTINCT agreement_id, type_id)` should work.

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't know count could take in more than one column!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to count distinct `(agreement_id, type_id)` tuples per `(cus_id, prod_category)` tuple.

"Per (cus_id, prod_category) tuple" translates to `GROUP BY cus_id, prod_category` in SQL.

And we count distinct (agreement_id, type_id) tuples with `COUNT(DISTINCT agreement_id, type_id)`.

```
SELECT cus_id, prod_category, COUNT(DISTINCT agreement_id, type_id) AS distinct_count
FROM mytable
GROUP BY cus_id, prod_category
ORDER BY cus_id, prod_category;
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use the following two level aggregation query:

```sql
SELECT cus_id, prod_category, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT cus_id, prod_category, agreement_id, type_id
    FROM yourTable
) t
GROUP BY cus_id, prod_category;
```

The inner distinct query de-duplicated tuples, and the outer aggregation query counts the number of distinct tuples per customer and product category.

Comment: But this woudn't work if there were multiple rows having same prod_category and type_id but different agreement_id for example 
 prod_category being 0    and type_id being  -1  and having agreement_id as different vlaues such as 956 and 1000

Comment: @hjun: I have mentioned this in the request comments. We don't know your DBMS, so we cannot give you the solution, as the syntax for counting distinct tuples is dependent from the DBMS.